# Passing a dynamic String from one form to another in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I have 2 forms `Form1` and `Form2`.

In Form1 i have a `backgroundWorker`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.Show();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int k = 0;bool b=true;
        while (b==true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            k++;
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, "data");
            if (k >= 100)
                b = false;
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string str = "";
        str+=e.UserState.ToString();
        label1.Text += str;
    }
}
```

In `Form2` I have one label `label2`.

**How can i display the same content of label1 in form1 on label2 in form 2 dynamically.**

Please Help with an example.

Comment: How do you call the second form? In general I would overload the constructor of form 2, and pass the value of label 1 as parameter.

Comment: Are both forms / open / updated at the same time? Or is this a one time thing, when form 2 opens, to pass it a value?

Comment: Both forms are open at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an `Action` that you call when you update the `label` on `Form1`

```
public Action<string> UpdateFormAction {get; set;}   

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string str = "";
    str+=e.UserState.ToString();
    label1.Text += str;
    UpdateForm2(label1.Text);
}

private void UpdateForm2(string text)
{
   Action<string> handler = UpdateFormAction;
   if (handler != null)
       handler(text);
}
```

Then depending on where you instantiate your forms, you can hook up the `Action`

Comment: David, could you please explain it completely.I am a beginner in c#.